# Python restarts shell in IDLE

Tags: python, emcee

I am using [EMCEE](http://dfm.io/emcee/current/) Python package which is MCMC method.
When I choose `500` steps and `300` walkers everything is OK and after couple of hours I have the results and outputs. But as I change them to higher steps `(800)` and higher walkers `(400)` after many hours shell is restarted by python without any outputs and results.

I read the questions about this issue in stackoverflow, but I could not understand what should I do for this such a problem. Bwcause forlower steps and walkers I have the answer.

I am wondering iif there is any problem with RAM? with IDLE? or what?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer.
My laptop has Cori3 intel core and 4Gb DDR3 Ram. I improve the RAM to 8Gb and until and with `600` steps and `400` walkers I got the results.

I think, Python has many problems due to alarming wrong error.